# How to get a list output from forEach loop in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two different lists of same objects but different properties and with a common identifier in those objects. I would like to iterate over the first list and get the corresponding object from the second (which has common properties) and then wrap those objects around and finally add that object to a list using Java Streams.

This is the example I have taken.

```
private class Person {
        private String name;
        private boolean isSenior;

        private Person(String name, boolean isSenior) {
            this.name = name;
            this.isSenior = isSenior;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean isSenior() {
            return isSenior;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + ": " + isSenior;
        }
    }

    private class PersonWrapper {
        private Person jrPerson;
        private Person srPerson;

        private PersonWrapper(Person jrPerson, Person srPerson) {
            this.jrPerson = jrPerson;
            this.srPerson = srPerson;
        }

        public Person getJrPerson() {
            return jrPerson;
        }

        public Person getSrPerson() {
            return srPerson;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return jrPerson.toString() + "-" + srPerson.toString();
        }
    }
```

Now, in the main class, I will create two list instances like this

```
List<Person> jrPersons = new ArrayList<>();
List<Person> srPersons = new ArrayList<>();
```

and add the objects in the following manner

```
jrList.add(new Person("John", false));
jrList.add(new Person("Paul", false));
jrList.add(new Person("Mike", false));

seniorList.add(new Person("John", true));
seniorList.add(new Person("Paul", true));
seniorList.add(new Person("Mike", true));
```

Now, I want to iterate over the jrList and find the corresponding Person object in the srList (same name). Then I would wrap these objects as `PersonWrapper` and that object to a list.

So far, this is what I have been doing

```
List<PersonWrapper> wrapperList = new ArrayList<>();

jrList.forEach(jr -> seniorList.stream().filter(sr -> jr.getName().equals(sr.getName())).map(sr -> new PersonWrapper(jr, sr)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Now, I would like to know how the `Collectors.toList()` can be substituted by `wrapperList` or how the output from `Collectors.toList()` be added to `wrapperList`.

Please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [Lino's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618049/how-to-get-a-list-output-from-foreach-loop-in-java-8-streams/50618104#50618104) answer is certainly correct. I would argue that if a given person object in `jrList` can only ever have one corresponding match in `seniorList` maximum, in other words, if it's a 1-1 relationship then you can improve upon the solution given by [Lino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618049/how-to-get-a-list-output-from-foreach-loop-in-java-8-streams/50618104#50618104) by finding the first match as follows:

```
List<PersonWrapper> resultSet = jrList.stream()
                .map(p -> seniorList.stream()
                        .filter(sr -> p.getName().equals(sr.getName()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(q -> new PersonWrapper(p, q))
                        .get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if there is no guarantee that each person in `jrList` will have a corresponding match in `seniorList` then change the above query to:

```
List<PersonWrapper> resultSet = jrList.stream()
                .map(p -> seniorList.stream()
                        .filter(sr -> p.getName().equals(sr.getName()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(q -> new PersonWrapper(p, q))
                        .orElse(null))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The difference is that now instead of calling `get()` on the result of `findFirst()` we provide a default with `orElse` in case `findFirst` cannot find the corresponding value and then we `filter` the `null` values out in the subsequent intermediate operation as they are not needed.

Comment: thanks for the new answer. I was trying to accomplish this requirement, but I couldn't do it so. Now, it is clear.

Comment: As of Java9 you might want to omit the `orElse()` and just use `.flatMap(p -> seniorList.stream()
                        .filter(sr -> p.getName().equals(sr.getName()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(q -> new PersonWrapper(p, q)).stream()` which flattens the optional to a stream

Comment: @Lino good shout, in which case we no longer need the subsequent filter for null elements. I had to restrict myself here as the question is tagged with java-8 hence didn’t mention anything about java-9. But yeah that’s a good shout. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using a `forEach` just use streams from the beginning:

```
List<PersonWrapper> wrapperList = jrList.stream()
    .flatMap(jr -> seniorList.stream()
         .filter(sr -> jr.getName().equals(sr.getName()))
         .map(sr -> new PersonWrapper(jr, sr))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By using `flatMap` you can *flatten* a stream of streams (`Stream<Stream<PersonWrapper>>`) into a single stream (`Stream<PersonWrapper>`)

If you can't instantiate `wrapperList` by yourself or really need to append to it. You can alter above snippet to following:

```
List<PersonWrapper> wrapperList = new ArrayList<>();

jrList.stream()
    .flatMap(jr -> seniorList.stream()
         .filter(sr -> jr.getName().equals(sr.getName()))
         .map(sr -> new PersonWrapper(jr, sr))
    )
    .forEach(wrapperList::add);
```

Comment: Thanks @Lino. That served my purpose

Comment: can you also please explain how Stream<Stream<PersonWrapper>> is being created? By which operation in the above expression exactly? @Lino

Comment: @Ravi In the first snippet, you create a stream in the first line. Now imagine in the second line, instead of using `flatMap` use `map`. In the `map` operation we create another stream, `filter` that, and then `map` the results to a new `PersonWrapper` instance. You never terminate the stream, you're just adding opperations. So you're in fact mapping a `Person` to a `Stream<PersonWrapper>` which finally results in a `Stream<Stream<PersonWrapper>>`.

Comment: Thanks @Lino. Understood now. Also, can I know why adding `findFirst().get()` before `map(sr -> new PersonWrapper(jr, sr))` is giving me compile time error saying "Stream<Object>" cannot be converted to Unknown"?

Comment: Well I guess that is because `flatMap` expects a `Stream` to be returned. But by using `findFirst().get()` you're trying to return a `PersonalWrapper`

Comment: @Lino I believe the OP is trying to get only the first match as there will only ever be one match in the corresponding list maximum. I cannot guarantee this but after reading the question several times it seems as if that is the case _to me anyway_ so I decided to provide [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618049/how-to-get-a-list-output-from-foreach-loop-in-java-8-streams/50631163#50631163).

Answer (score -1):

Replace your looping logic with below code.

```
 jrList.forEach(jr -> seniorList.stream().filter(sr -> jr.getName().equals(sr.getName()))
                    .map(sr -> wrapperList.add(new PersonWrapper(jr, sr))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: using a side-effect in a `map` is not recommended. Also collecting to a list doesn't make sense as a terminal operation

Comment: This sounds like it works. Thanks @Dharita. Considering Lino's comment, I think his answer makes more sense